# Swift error Type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'

Tags: compiler-errors, swift, tuples

I want to factorize a number into its prime factors with the following code fragment, but I don't understand fully the given error-message (see in above title). First I tried using a Dictionary but I got stuck on sorting this dictionary by keys. Second I tried the tuple-version but now I'm stuck with the compiler-error.

Can anybody see whats wrong in the last line of the following code fragment?

```
var pfc : [(prime: Int, count: Int)] = []
pfc.append(prime: 2, count: 2)
pfc += [(prime: 3, count: 4)]
var p = 5, c = 1
pfc.append(prime: p, count: c)
```

In stack overflow similar questions can be found regarding String.Index, but the answers give me not enough clues yet. So any help would be very welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does pfc.append((prime: p, count: c))  work?

Comment: `append` has always been a little bit wack on arrays of tuples. Please [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/) for this behavior!

Comment: @sanz: Nope: the pfc.append((prime:p, count:c)) doesn't work, however pfc += [(prime:p, count:c)] DOES work! Note: I'm using Xcode6 Beta5.

Comment: @Nate I filed the bug to Apple (my first one) and am curious what they do with it. Thanks for the tip (and URL).

Comment: They definitely seem to be responding to Swift issues as they work on these betas. Even if it gets closed as a duplicate it's still valuable, since they can get a sense of how many people are running into the problem. FWIW, I think both the second and last line should error, since you aren't passing a tuple to the `append()` method, but individual arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very interesting, seems buggy as Nate mentions. I was able to work around it through some different syntax.

```
var pfc : [(prime: Int, count: Int)] = []

pfc.append(prime: 2, count: 2)

pfc += [(prime: 3, count: 4)]

var p = 5
var c = 1

var tuple = (prime: p, count: c)

pfc += [tuple]

pfc
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I used the following code-fragment without compiler issues: pfc += [(prime: p, count: c)]; 
    var newElement = (prime: p, count:c ); 
    pfc += [newElement]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the tuple in two sets of parenthesis instead of just one.

```
var pfc : [(prime: Int, count: Int)] = []
pfc.append((prime: 2, count: 2))
pfc += [(prime: 3, count: 4)]
var p = 5, c = 1
pfc.append((prime: p, count: c))
```

I think that the compiler thought you wanted to call a method called `Array.append(prime: Int, count: Int)` but that method couldn't be found for type `Array`

Comment: Unfortunately the pfc.append((prime: p, count: c)) gives me the following compiler-error (with Xcode6 Beta5) "Missing argument for parameter 'count' in call"